# How can I return a value from inside of multiple functions?

Tags: javascript, selenium

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
(function() {
    var origOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
        this.addEventListener('load', function() 
            console.log(this.responseText); //return this value
        });
        origOpen.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})();
```

I'm using selenium's execute_script() to execute the above code on to the website. How can I return `this.responseText` to a variable?

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like asynchronous programming and promises are your friend: https://github.com/kriskowal/q *(my favourite library)*

Comment: @MichalStefanow unfortunately, I'm here with limited resources. I'm executing that piece of Javascript on to an Iframe. So, I can't use external libraries. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

`this.responseText` obtain value when `XMLHttpRequest` responds, asynchronously.

If you need execute code when XMLHttpRequest finish you must pass as a callback, or call directly in the event; inside that call you can redirect the application flux.

Example, directly (I try not to change your original code):

```
function oCallback(responseText){
    console.log('continues execution');
    console.log(responseText);
}

(function() {
    var origOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
        this.addEventListener('load', function() 
            //console.log(this.responseText); //return this value
            oCallback(this.responseText);
        });
        origOpen.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})();
```